# API to force reanalyze of function (Alt-P)

Tags: ida, idapython

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on a function and hitting enter will force a reanalysis of the function (https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/485.shtml)

Is there a way to do this through API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ida_auto.auto_make_proc(addr)`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_auto.html#ida_auto.auto_make_proc) should do that.