# How to force IDA to analyze a function immediately?

Tags: ida, idapython, idapro-sdk

I think my question is probably related to this one:
[API to force reanalyze of function (Alt-P)](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19967/api-to-force-reanalyze-of-function-alt-p)

When I define a function at a certain location with IDAPython, I want IDA to analyze it immediately, before proceeding with auto-analysis of the rest of the IDB. Is there a way to force this to happen, or must I wait for the auto-analysis queue to get to my function later? As the linked question points out, doing this manually via the GUI does seem to make it happen immediately.

Answer (score 1):

[`ida_auto.auto_make_proc(addr)`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_auto.html#ida_auto.auto_make_proc)
should do that